# SQL - Retrieve top(X) records even when fewer than X exist

Tags: sql, random

In my application, there are several places where a random set of X items is displayed to the user. The UI calls for there to be exactly X items displayed. However, there is no guarantee there will be X items in the table. So, if there are not X items, I need to fill the results with random duplicates.

I need to write a query that is essentially:

```
SELECT TOP(@count) *
FROM Things
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

I'd like to be able to ask SQL for X records and get exactly X records back every time. Is there an easy way to accomplish this in SQL?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you expect SQL to do? Create new data?

Comment: That is a very good question. I hadn't thought about it like that. It would be convenient for the application to not have to worry about whether or not it got back the number of rows it asked for.

Comment: That's not convenient: it's silly. The application can determine how many rows it retrieved, and behave accordingly. If it asked for 5 movies named "A fish called wanda" does it really make sense to return 5 identical rows to the user, when there could only ever be one movie with that name? For what purpose?

Comment: I thought this was an interesting problem to solve. I can easily do this in C# if I so chose. I felt if there was an easy way to do it in sql and I could make only 1 call to the DB, it would be clean and efficient. Sarcasm is not appreciated.

Comment: `SELECT TOP(@count) T.*
FROM Things AS T CROSS APPLY sys.allcolumns SAC
ORDER BY NEWID()`

Comment: The application has a few places in the view where it shows a random set of X items and it needs exactly X items. Why is it so silly to ask the DB for a random set of X items and expect there to be X items in the result?

Comment: @SeattleLeonard The question at its core is valid, but it is underspecified (what should the padding rows contain?). On SO it is quite easy to earn hatred because there are indeed many horrible questions. For us, who answer a lot, this is frustrating. The hatred on this question is a false-positive. Sorry about that. Try asking this again in a well-specified way.

Comment: Thinking to that for a moment, having a tool to sample data could be *very* useful. Interesting :)

Comment: Wow, how 8 years makes a difference. I still think this is an interesting question. However, today, I would never ask SQL to make this kind of decision. The advice I'd give to my former self is to get back from SQL what exists, and then in the middle tier (if needed) create the duplicates.

Answer (score 8):

Well, I have a solution, but I still think the requirements are ridiculous. This assumes that the source table (in my case, `@t`) has at least one row. If you have zero rows, what exactly are you demoing?

```
DECLARE @count INT = 17; -- here is whatever your 'X' is; pick any value


DECLARE @t TABLE(i INT);

-- just insert 10 arbitrary values; test with @count = 5, @count = 247, etc.

INSERT @t VALUES(150),(170),(50),(100),(200),(230),(20),(800),(180),(632);

DECLARE @x INT; SELECT @x = COUNT(*) FROM @t;

SELECT TOP (@count) x.* FROM 
(
  -- limit this set to @count:
  SELECT TOP (@count) * FROM @t ORDER BY NEWID()
) AS x 
OUTER APPLY 
(
  -- limit this set the ratio of @count to rows in @t
  -- add one to round up for integer division:
  SELECT TOP (@count/@x+1) * FROM sys.all_objects 
  WHERE @count > @x -- only evaluate this subquery if we don't have enough rows
) AS y
ORDER BY NEWID(); -- need a 2nd ORDER BY in my tests to avoid pockets of same values
```

Hat tip to [@billinkc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/181965/billinkc) for [the `CROSS APPLY` idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20224734/sql-retrieve-topx-records-even-when-fewer-than-x-exist/20226028#comment30160647_20224734).

Comment: Thank you for giving an actual answer to the question. In my case, we can assume there will be at least 1 row.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up creating my own solution.

```
DECLARE @count INT = 10; 

DECLARE @ids TABLE(id INT);

WHILE ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @ids) < @count)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @ids
        SELECT TOP(@count) ID
        FROM Things
        ORDER BY NEWID()
END

SELECT TOP(@count) t.*
FROM Things t
JOIN @ids ON t.ID = [@ids].id
```

Comment: Why would you want to use a `WHILE` loop for this? Have you checked the performance?

Comment: @AaronBertrand who needs set logic when you can WHILE?!?! stop being such a tightwad.

Comment: 99.9999% of the time, that while loop will essentially just be an if statement that runs twice. Once to start the loop, and once to exit it. If sql had a do/while it would only check once. Considering my "silly" requirements, I think this is a reasonable compromise.

Comment: @SeattleLeonard the point is not your choice of looping structure, the point is ***that*** you chose a looping structure instead of a set-based solution. the relational model is set-based so your best performance will come with using a set-based solution like Aaron provided. Also, calling people who are trying to help you "trolls" is not a good way to continue getting help. Downvotes will come because you've given a less-superior answer in the face of other answers.

Comment: Won't the outer apply of thousands of records have a performance impact when compared to only retrieving 10 records?

Comment: Also, the trolls comment was not meant for people actually helping such as Aaron. It was meant for the people who didn't read the post before answering and giving an answer that didn't fit the requirements, however silly they are, or responded with sarcasm. I believe the question I asked had merit and got 4 downvotes before any reasonable answer was given. Essentially I got downvotes because people didn't like my PM's requirements. If that doesn't scream troll, I don't know what does.

Comment: Not sure why you think the OUTER APPLY is going to look at thousands of rows. Did you actually try it? Did you compare the duration and other metrics compared to your while loop?

Answer (score 1):

Having a quick glimpse to table data can help when working on a query performance problem, 
it can help in identifying recurring values, nulls and understand the data.

I think Aaron has the best answer, however just to mention, answers using TOP... ORDER BY NEWID() have a big performance problem for large table, 
they induce at least a complete index (clustered or not) scan, 
because the TOP is done after the SORT wich is done after 
the NEWID for all records.

Another solution discussed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc441928.aspx) 
use BINARY_CHECKSUM, RAND but seems to be flawed  according to comments.

Yet another simple solution would be to use the TABLESAMPLE option that has been added to Sql2005

```
SELECT * FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail TABLESAMPLE (1000 ROWS)
```

see [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189108.aspx)

However, they are conditions to it's use 
"..    The sample does not have to be a truly random sample at the level of individual rows.
    Rows on individual pages of the table are not correlated with other rows on the same page. "
and according to the description and notes, the output seems to be not completely random.
And also, the output does not always have the desired number of rows, [see](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1308/retrieving-random-data-from-sql-server-with-tablesample/)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in T-SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
 SELECT TOP(@count) *
 FROM Things
 ORDER BY NEWID()
) x
UNION ALL
SELECT DummyValuesHere
FROM Numbers
WHERE Numbers.ID <= (@count - (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Things))
```

You need a `Numbers` table for that. We just append (`UNION ALL`) the right number of dummy rows.

Now that you see how horrible the query is, consider doing the job in the application. SQL is not a good tool for such queries.

Comment: Except that I don't want dummy values. That would be silly showing the user a bunch of bad data.

Comment: @SeattleLeonard well you didn't say what you want to show :) Just insert anything you want in the second part of the UNION ALL. You can even take "backfill" rows from `Things`.

Comment: @SeattleLeonard One could argue it would be equally silly to show row 1, then row 1 again, then row 2, then row 2 again, then row 2 again one more time. (In the case where `@count = 5` and there are only 2 rows in the table.)

Comment: One could argue that, but then one would also have to argue that the requirements of the application (written by people very far removed from me) are also silly. :)

Comment: @Seattle can you elaborate on what value they see in showing exactly n rows all the time, even if it includes redundant duplicates? Is it really to avoid coding any logic into the application so that it understands how many rows actually exist?

Comment: Sure. Don't think of it as rendering rows in a table. Think of it as showing a bunch of tiles in a Metro UI. The specific use case would be demos of the software. The salesperson sets up a brand new instance and there are blocks in the UI that show random items that meet a certain criteria. If there isn't enough data in the system to fill out the UI, because no content very little content has been created, they don't want big empty holes in the UI. It doesn't look "pretty".

Comment: Explain what Metro UI is.. Did you forget we're database people (like swamp people only know swamp stuff)?